# Can't iterate over http post return array

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to do a simple iteration over the objects returned from an Http request and can't. I've tried map, and now trying a simple for loop and am running into typing issues. Here's the code:

```
this.apiService.getTracsStartEvents( data, options ).subscribe((events) => {
  /**
   * Now return a list of Mission Start geoJSON objects to plot
   */
  let startMissionObjects = [];
  for ( const missionStart of **events** ){
    startMissionObjects.push( this.posUpdateRecToGeoJsonRec( missionStart ));

  }
});
```

events is the problem child it won't let me iterate over. Here's the http call:

```
  public getTracsStartEvents( data, options ) {
    return this.httpClient.post<any[]>(url, data, options );
```

I know from logging that the http calls returns an array of objects, here is the log:

```
events= 
(3)[{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {imei: "300434030116030", messagecode: 10, messagecodelabel: "Start Track", alt: 575, lat: 37.734695, …}
1: {imei: "300434030230110", messagecode: 10, messagecodelabel: "Start Track", alt: 374.86835845248, lat: 33.82410407066345, …}
2: {imei: "300434063742260", messagecode: 10, messagecodelabel: "Start Track", alt: 120.92451174360001, lat: 36.97652578353882, …}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I've even tried typing the post to return an array of the objects it is actually returning. But nothing will let me iterate over the result. I know I must be doing something dumb....

Comment: Can you provide what the `events` object looks like when you `console.log` it in your `subscribe` handler?

Comment: just updated post with console log

Answer (score 0):

After the discussion in the comments what I think is happening is that you are calling the method with options that contain `{observe: 'events'}`. This means that you get all the event stream and you get events for every action and the progress of the call. Check the [documentation for HttpEvent](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpEvent).

The return type from the [HttpClient post](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post) method is determined by the options you specify in the post call. What you need to do is to specify in the options `{observe: 'body', responseType:`json`}` to get just the array in the body.

```
const options = {observe: 'body', responseType: 'json'};
this.apiService.getTracsStartEvents( data, options ).subscribe((events) => {
  /**
   * Now return a list of Mission Start geoJSON objects to plot
   */
  let startMissionObjects = [];
  events.forEach((missionStart) => {
    startMissionObjects.push( this.posUpdateRecToGeoJsonRec( missionStart ));
  });
});
```

Comment: I'l already tried that. I get the error 'Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'HttpEvent<any[]>'.' when I try and use a forEach array.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Looks like you are getting a raw `HttpResponse` object. Don't know what you send in the options since I think the default is that you get just the body parsed from JSON.

Comment: Not working either. The body keyword generates error Property 'body' does not exist on type 'HttpEvent<any[]>. I thought this would have been such a simple thing to do...

Comment: You need to set in the options `{ observe: 'body'}` to get just the array. Do you set something else? The result you are getting is for `{observe: 'events'}` which gives you also progress events what I think you don't want. I will again update the answer. :)

Comment: the result of the array of 3 objects is the output for body. When I change the options to response or events I get a whole lot more as the response. Somehow I need to be able to cast or override the typing the compiler is forcing.

Comment: You need to set the options to `{observe: 'body', responseType: 'json'}` as I put also in the answer or find the correct override which has this setting as default. Then you will get just the array.

Comment: The body is the 3 returned objects. My original problem of not being able to iterate of the returned response remains. I can hardcode references to events[0], events[1] etc., but that doesn't do me any good since the number of responses is dynamic. Somehow I need to be able to iterate of the POST response, but I'm beginning to think there is no way.

Comment: Then the problem is in what your service is returning. I think it does not return a JSON array. Can you add the JSON that he service returns? Please see this [StackBlitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngoninitloaddata?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnow-running.component.ts) I made for a different answer that does exactly what you want to do and it works.

Comment: OMG! THANK YOU! All I was missing was :any attached to the events in my subscribe. Now it works exactly as I need. I thought I'd tried every combination of adding a type to events, but didn't try the simplest one. Thank you so much!